# DC motor design without brushed or electronic commutation

Tags: motor, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor

When applying DC voltage to the coils, will this motor exhibit torque?

Rotor is comprised of 24 iron blocks which pass through two stationary copper coils. The flow of current within the coils is direct and steady. When passing through the left stationary coil, an individual iron block has magnetic south pole on its outer end; likewise, when passing through the right stationary coil, it has magnetic north pole on its outer end. The stator magnets push/pull on iron blocks in similar fashion to a traditional DC motor. I thoroughly described my design to GPT-4, and it assesses that the motor will indeed have torque.

Here's an animation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJspzb5iWi8

[image]

Comment: Chatbots do **not** understand what you tell them.  They generate sequences of reasonable looking words that pick up where your prompt left off.  They can no more "assess" things than pigs can fly.

Answer (score 1):

The coils can be replaced by permanent magnets, and then you get something
that would break conservation of energy.

To me this suggests that there  is some force that is not accounted for that is cancelling the presumed torque, possibly this is the forces on the rotor where it passes between coils.

it seems that you essentially have a variable reluctance machine, the slugs will not want to pass from the forwards polarised region into the reverse polarised region.

Comment: So are you thinking that the two iron blocks passing in-between the two coils are cancelling out all of the torque of the other 22 iron blocks?

Comment: most of the others make no torque